# Mongodb db.stats in a middleware performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, middleware

I am using MongoDB 3.0.7 and node js native mongodb driver 2.0.48 with express js. When the node js was running and Mongo server stopped working due to some system error, to handle that situation I have added the db.stats() method as middleware to check for each call and if error occurs,  redirecting to custom error page.

```
app.use(function dbStats(req, res, next){
            db.stats(function(err, stats){
                if (err) {
                    res.render("error");
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
        });
```

Will this implementation cause the performance issue? Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: It'll cause a performance issue .. as each request is now checking for db state..

Comment: Is there any alternative way to handle this scenario?